# Change Fill Color of CALayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, svg

Is it possible to set the fill color of a CALayer that has already been drawn on screen?

I am using SVGKit to load a SVG image into a UIView and everything is working very well but I need to change the fill color. I have read up on CAShapeLayer.fillColor and think that it can be done easily but I don't seem to see an easy way to do it with a CALayer? I really do hope it can be done.

May be someone might even be able to suggest if a CALayer can be converted to a CAShapeLayer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Look at the docs for [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and you'll see

```
@property CGColorRef backgroundColor
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have checked out CALayer background color which works as expected but I need to change the actual Fill Color as the background needs to remain ClearColor.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same EcksMedia, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Why does this question have -4 ?